# Bones not parenting properly?

Tags: rigging, armature

I have made this low-poly character mesh, and so far added bones from the torso to the head. [image: FrontTorsoShot]

So, my next step is to add the legs. Unfortunately, when I extrude from the torso bone to the top of the legs, the hip/leg bones don't parent to the torso bone. When I move the torso, the legs just stay totally still and they disconnect from the torso.[image: AngledTorsoDisconnect]

Even when I parent the bones manually, both in offset and connected mode, the torso simply does not move the leg/hip bones. It does move the others though. This is a re-rig of an old model I made, and I did not have this problem, but i don't remember exactly what I did so I'm not sure if I'm forgetting something. This leads me to believe that there might be a parent limit on bones, but I highly doubt it. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Extruding from the base of a bone doesn't automatically create a parent relationship.

1. Select your extruded leg bone
2. Select your back bone (keeping both selected)
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
4. Select keep offset

The bones won't move each other in edit mode because edit mode is for positioning/creating bones. However, the leg bone will now be parented in pose mode.

Answer (score 0):

After extruding your bones as you have done you need to parent them once more as Aoradon said and if it doesn't work then it will be a weight paint problem just select the bone in pose mode and then go into weight paint mode and then manually paint weight manually. You can also take help of tutorials online there are numerous number of tutorials on weight painting in blender.